# Como puedo hacer un refresh y cargar nuevamente las celdas de una tabla? en Java

Tags: java, sql, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy precisando cargar nuevamente la tabla con los datos de la *DB* luego de hacer un un `remove` para limpiar la tabla.

Ya hecha la consulta y llenado las celdas de la tabla pruebo en limpiarla para llenar nuevamente los celdas pero sin éxito.

```
String query = "SELECT id,name,email FROM contacts";
ResultSet rs = miStatament.executeQuery(query);
java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while (rs.next()) {
  item = new TableItem(tabla, SWT.NONE);
  for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
    item.setText(i - 1, rs.getString(i));
    if ( rs.next() == false) {
      //No se como seguir la logica aca
    }
  }
}
```

Agradezco quien me pueda guiar. 
Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitaba era hacer un refresh de la tabla, de esta manera puedo soneguirlo.

```
button1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
System.out.println("Se ha seleccionado el botón");
TableItem item;
```

Consulta

```
String query = "SELECT id,name,email FROM contacts";
ResultSet rs = miStatament.executeQuery(query);
java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
```

Recorrido para poder cargar las celdas

```
  while (rs.next()) {
  item = new TableItem(tabla, SWT.NONE);
  for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
    item.setText(i - 1, rs.getString(i));
} 
 catch (SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) 
{
 }
   });
```

Borrar contenido de la tabla

```
button3.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() 
{
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
System.out.println("Se ha seleccionado el botón");
TableItem item;
tabla.removeAll();

public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) 
{

            }
        });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero le sea de útil este código.
Saludos.